# Vue JS use of vsvg to compile svg icons

Tags: svg, vue.js

Hi guys I have installed vue-svgicon in Vue Js through the article https://alligator.io/vuejs/using-svg-icons/

and when converting svg icons into js files to show them via Vue Js I have noticed that icons have lost color and are only in black color, so if there were multiple colors on icons they will only be in one color. 
Is there any way to compile icons vie vue-svgicon to preserve natural set of colors? Thanks

I have used npm run generate-icons to generate new icons.

Comment: Sounds like an issue I was having earlier with slightly different tools that generated icons from an svg file. It could be that your svg file is in e.g. Inkscape SVG format, so you need to save it in Plain SVG format instead.

Comment: In case you're using their [example CSS](https://github.com/MMF-FE/vue-svgicon#use-generated-icon) both `stroke: currentColor` and `fill: currentColor` would override the original colours, also check your SVGO settings (vue-svgicon makes use of it) for something like `convertColors: { currentColor: true }`